# What is the call back url I should provide for spree social

Tags: twitter-oauth, spree, spree-auth-devise

I am using spree_social gem, for social media logins using facebook and google.

How ever while I am trying to create an app in twitter, they say call back url is invalid

`http://localhost:3000/users/auth/twitter` This is what I am giving as the call back url. What should I give the call back url to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's mentioned in spree_social extension the callback url for

- Twitter, `http://localhost:3000` (development) or `http://your-site.com` (production) (mentioned [here](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_social#twitter)).
- Facebook, no callback url required (see [here](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_social#facebook)).
- Google, `http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback` (development) or `http://your-site.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback` (production).

Comment: Thanks for answering